# How to Generate .AAB file and Sign Android app Bundle using azure pipeline

Tags: android, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to generate an Android app bundle(.aab) file using the Azure pipeline and facing an issue while generating the Android App Bundle file.

I have used the below Gradle task to generate and sign the .aab file. but, It generating the .APK file. I want to generate .aab file.

```
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    tasks: 'buildRelease'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
    spotBugsAnalysis: false
```

Here is the script, Where I use jarsigner to sign the .aab file:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Signing and aligning AAB file(s) app\build\outputs\bundle\release\app-release.aab'
  inputs:
    script: 'jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -keystore $(KeyStoreFile.secureFilePath) -storepass $(StorePassword) -keypass $(KeyPassword) $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab $(KeyStoreAlias)'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the Gradle tasks:
I needed to change the `tasks` value '`buildRelease`' to '`:app:bundleRelease`' to generate the .aab file.

Here is the .yaml file which I used to generate and sign .aab file:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'AndroidApp.jks'

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    tasks: ':app:bundleRelease'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
    spotBugsAnalysis: false


- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Signing and aligning AAB file(s) app\build\outputs\bundle\release\app-release.aab'
  inputs:
    script: 'jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -keystore $(KeyStoreFile.secureFilePath) -storepass $(StorePassword) -keypass $(KeyPassword) $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab $(KeyStoreAlias)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

There is below variables that I created and used in the signing task:

```
KeyStoreFile.secureFilePath
StorePassword
KeyPassword
KeyStoreAlias
```

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly I added the signing process in the app gradle file (this process is executed only for release build). With this, after all builds (in your machine or in azure pipeline) the apk/aab generated will be signed.
I have in my project a keystore.properties like this :

```
storePassword=****
keyPassword=****
keyAlias=****
storeFile=/** jks path **/
```

And the app build.gradle file contains this signing process for release build variante using my properties file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

// Create a variable called keystorePropertiesFile, and initialize it to your
// keystore.properties file, in the rootProject folder.
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")

// Initialize a new Properties() object called keystoreProperties.
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()

// Load your keystore.properties file into the keystoreProperties object.
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

def versionPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("version.properties")

// Initialize a new Properties() object called versionProperties.
def versionProperties = new Properties()

// Load your version.properties file into the versionProperties object.
versionProperties.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropertiesFile))

....
android {
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 30
defaultConfig {
    //.....
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        //+ specify the signing config
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
.....
```

**One thing is missing here** !! How to change jks path (which azure pipeline doesn't know) in keystore.properties file ?
This is done by **azure pipeline** with a task which generate this file before build task using [azure variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) for passwords and alias AND [azure pipeline secure file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops) for jks file.

```
steps:
  #get the keyStore file encoded
  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    name: yourNameHere
    displayName: 'Get KeyStore file'
    inputs:
      secureFile: 'yourKeyStoreBase64Encoded.txt'
    # decode the keystore base-64 encoded string of our jks certificate into storeFile
  - script: |
      cat $(yourNameHere.secureFilePath) | base64 --decode > $(KeyStore.Name)
    displayName: Create jks certificate
    # rewrite keystore.properties
  - script: |
      printf 'storePassword=%s\nkeyPassword=%s\nkeyAlias=%s\nstoreFile=%s' $(Store.Password) $(KeyStore.Password) $(KeyStore.KeyAlias) ../$(KeyStore.Name) > keystore.properties
    displayName: Generate keystore.properties
```

After the task Gradle@2 with command ":app:bundleRelease", the aab generated is signed thanks to gradle signing config.
Then I get this aab and publish it to artifactory like this:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: |
      **/outputs/**/*.aab
    targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
    displayName: Copy and .aab files to artifact staging directory
 - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
   inputs:
     pathToPublish: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
     artifactName: 'drop'
    displayName: Publish artifacts directory
```

Comment: This is also a good way to sign the App bundle file. but, the question was "How to generate .aab file and sign it?". so, Can you mention also how you generate the file in the answer? Thanks!

Comment: To generate the aab I use the Gradle@2 task like you with "app:bundleRelease" command. With my app level build.gradle signing config, the app generated is signed.

Comment: Can you share your YAML file here? so, I can take a look and get an idea of how you have set up all the pipeline steps. Thanks!

Comment: First step is creating the keystore.properties file, then Gradle@2 task with 'app:bundleRelease', then the two tasks to copy and publish the signed aab. You have all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Please just a quick question. What will be the value of KeyStoreFile.secureFilePath in azure variables

Comment: In the variable, You have to set the .jks file path in it. Here is the reference to generate the .jks file: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key
Thanks!